# dbus how to reconnect to a new session bus daemon

Tags: c, daemon, dbus, c-api

As far as I understand it, a dbus user connects to the session bus daemon if the environment defines two variables like:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-1cAnv4I,guid=3a453c40b5034f
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=102
```

If the daemon stops and we start a new daemon by dbus-launch, we will get new values for the environment. In this case how the new values can be propagated into a running user process without restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic to reconnect to a new dbus daemon should involve a few components and events:

- A bus-monitor which tells the application whether the bus is still up, or down, or restarted.

  - When the bus is restarted, the new bus address will be sent to the application.
- The application which responses to the down and restart events:

  - If the bus is down or restarted, close everything and go back to the beginning of the bus cycle before the call to `dbus_bus_get()`.
  - If the bus is down, wait till bus is restarted.
  - If the bus is restarted, modify the process environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to the new dbus address, then proceed the new bus cycle by calling `dbus_bus_get()`.

If you read the code in `dbus/dbus_bus.c` and follow the functions `dbus_bus_get()` -> `internal_bus_get()` -> `init_connections_unlocked()`, you may see the above logic is what you can do. Or you may see other approaches of doing the same thing. Please leave a comment if you know other approaches or have other thinking.

Edit: Verified the approach with more details:

- After `dbus_bus_get()`, call `dbus_connection_set_exit_on_disconnect(conn,FALSE)` so that the application will keep running after the dbus daemon disconnects.
- Add a dumb signal receiver that calls `dbus_connection_read_write(conn,0)`. If the dbus connection is lost it returns a `FALSE`. That is used to decide when to close the dbus cycle. Drain the message queue with `dbus_connection_pop_message(conn)` despite the connection is closed.
- Close dbus cycle by `dbus_connection_unref(conn)` then `dbus_shutdown()`. If it is not shutdown the call to `dbus_bus_get()` will not make use of the new environment variable.
- Use `setenv(char * name, char * value)` to set session bus address.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get address after restart is to query corresponding X11 property:

dbus-daemon sets `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` property of `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SELECTION_[hostname]_[uuid]` selection owner (uuid is content of `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` ). This is the code I use to read the this value: https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/lib/address-x11.js

Comment: I don't have X running. I need a way to update the bus address into a running bus user process without restarting it. Thanks for the solution that may be useful to x users though.